# How to access python return value from bash script

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to understand how to access from a bash script the return value of a python script.

Clarifying through an example:

**foo.py**

```
def main():
    print ("exec main..")
    return "execution ok"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**start.sh**

```
script_output=$(python foo.py 2>&1)
echo $script_output
```

If I run the bash script, this prints the message "exec main..".

How can I store in *script_output* the return value (*execution ok*)? 
If I direct *execution ok* to stdout, the script_output will capture all the stdout (so the 2 print statement).

Is there any way to implement this?

Thanks!
Alessio

Comment: I think a more natural solution is for the python script to write to a file, which will then be read by the bash script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a proper exit code from your script using the `sys.exit()` module. Usually commands return 0 on successful completion of a script.

```
import sys

def main():
    print ("exec main..")
    sys.exit(0)
```

and capture it in shell script with a simple conditional. Though the exit code is 0 by default and need *not* be passed explicitly, using `sys.exit()` gives control to return non-zero codes on error cases wherever applicable to understand some inconsistencies with the script.

```
if python foo.py 2>&1 >/dev/null; then
    echo 'script ran fine'
fi
```

Comment: Is `sys.exit(0)` necessary? You can automatically get the exit status through `$?`, if you want to notify user that this script ran successfully manually then only we use `sys.exit(code)`

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Yes the documentation says it is optional. But I think if you have control over the script it is safe to send the code to ensure it

Comment: hey @Inian your solution looks more elegant than write something to stderr and grab the output of it from bash. It is close enough to what I was looking for! thanks!

Comment: @AvinashRaj: sys.exit([error code]) is necessary since the python script could end on error internally but the python process will return zero anyway. That way you can force the error signaling to other processes.

Comment: can you explain what your command is doing? especially the dev null part? `python foo.py 2>&1 >/dev/null`?

Comment: Redirect both stdout and stderr to null area.

Answer (score 5):

You can get the previous command's output status through `$?`. If the python script ran successfully without any `stderr`, it should return `0` as exit code else it would return `1` or any number other than 0.

```
#!/bin/bash
python foo.py 2>&1 /dev/null
script_output=$?
echo $script_output
```

Comment: can you explain what your command is doing? especially the dev null part? `python foo.py 2>&1 >/dev/null`?

Answer (score 3):

Bash contains only return code in `$?`, so you can't use it to print the text from python's `return`.
My solution is write in to the stderr in python script, next print only stderr in bash:

```py
import sys
    
    
def main():
    print ("exec main..")
    sys.stderr.write('execution ok\n')
    return "execution ok"
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Bash:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
    
script_output=$(python foo.py 1>/dev/null)
echo $script_output
```

Output:

```sh
execution ok
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid to write anything to stderr here, I'm sorry if I have not specified in my question.

Comment: @AlessioG well, I think Inian's solution is the best for you.

Comment: can you explain what your command is doing? especially the dev null part? `python foo.py 2>&1 >/dev/null`?